# Zen Coding CSS in TextMate doesn't expand anything

Tags: css, textmate, emmet

I've installed …

1. TextMate.Zen.CSS.1.3.1.zip
2. TextMate.Zen.HTML.1.3.1.zip
3. Zen.Coding-TextMate.v0.7.zip

… and using version 1.5.11 (1635)

HTML expansion seems to work fine. But no CSS abbreviation expands. In Google Code I didn't find an issue with TextMate and ZC CSS.

What could be the problem? Tried CMD + E and Tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try reloading the bundles?

Bundles -> Bundle editor -> Reload Bundles

Also did you select "CSS" from the filetype in the bottom left corner of textmate? Can you see "CSS Zen" in there as well?

Comment: I just switched to CSS and it works. And in HTML (within <style>) it works as well. I haven't a clue why it works now.
Anyway, thanks for answering!